# Remove first and last line from files

Tags: php, file-io

I am brand new to PHP and I have thousands of records I need to analyze. It appears that the first 2 lines and the last line of each record need to be removed. Is there some type of line count function that I could use to put each line into an array and then delete the first two and do like a max count to get the last line and then delete that? I am at a loss and appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are we talking about database (MySQL / PostgreSQL / etc.) records here, or indeed files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = file("file.txt");

array_shift($file); // Removing the first line
array_shift($file); // Removing the second line

array_pop($file); // Removing last line

// Creating the new file:

$fp = fopen("newFile.txt", "a+");

for ($x=0; $x < sizeof($file); $x++)
{
fputs($fp, $file[$x]. "\n");
}

fclose($fp);

?>
```

Comment: And if we're talking about a multi-gigabyte file? That's one helluva lot of  data to slurp into an array.

Comment: If you are dealing with multi-gigabyte files, I think the bash script language is more fast then PHP. As our friend "Marc B" answered above.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're on a Unix/Linux host, you'd be better off using some simple shell tools to do this for you. Specifically `wc -l`, `head`, and `tail`.

```
for i in *.txt; do
    lines=`wc -l $i`
    tail $(($lines - 2)) $i | head $(($lines - 1)) > /fixed/files/$i
done
```

not tested, YMMV, etc... but should get the idea across.

Comment: +1 Shell tools always before messing with a bigger scripting language.